# How to Change the Size of an Element Within a Custom Pushpin in BingMaps for Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

I have a custom pushpin which contains an Ellipse, and I would like to change its size programtically in the C# code behind. I am able to change the pushpin size, however, this affects its location on the map.

Is there a way for me to address the ellipse directly through a render transform or by directly changing its height and width?

Here is the xaml:

```
<map:Pushpin Location="51.4,-0.2" >
    <map:Pushpin.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Fill="Red" Opacity="0.7" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2.5">
                 <Ellipse.RenderTransform>   
                     <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="18" />
                 </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
             </Ellipse>
         </ControlTemplate>
     </map:Pushpin.Template>
</map:Pushpin>
```

Here is the C# I am using at present which changes the Pushpin sizes (currently to a random number):

```
private void MapItemsSizeChange()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    ScaleTransform pin_st = new ScaleTransform();

    if (mainMap != null)
    {
        foreach (UIElement UI in mainMap.Children)
        {
            if (UI is Pushpin)
            {
                var pin = UI as Pushpin;

                if (pin != null)
                {
                    double x = rnd.Next(5, 20);
                    x = x / 10;

                    pin_st.ScaleX = x;
                    pin_st.ScaleY = x;

                    UI.RenderTransform = pin_st;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/06/04/Resizing-and-Auto-Scaling-Pushpin-in-Bing-Maps-Silverlight.aspx